# Exporting Table Contents from Angular to Excel Invokes Error When Attempting To Open Downloaded File

Tags: html, excel, angular, typescript

I am making a general application to make a table in Angular and then export that table to excel using the `xlsx` library and StackBlitz for development. No errors are thrown in the code itself but when I try to open the downloaded file, excel basically tells me that the file extension is invalid.

**The error I am encountering**
[image: Excel Error]

**What I've done to debug the issue**

Given the nature of the error I've mostly looked for typos in my code such as `xslx` vs `xlsx` etc. but to no avail it doesn't seem as if that's the problem. I have tried downloading the table as a CSV which seems to download ok except the table headers are not included (something I am also trying to fix) in the CSV file, but I can then successfully change the file extension from `.csv` to `.xlsx` with no problems.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('TABLE', { static: false }) TABLE: ElementRef;  
  title = 'Excel';  

  constructor() {
    console.log('e')
  }
xport() {
  const workSheet: xlsx.WorkSheet = xlsx.utils.table_to_sheet(this.TABLE.nativeElement)
  const workBook: xlsx.WorkBook = xlsx.utils.book_new()
  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'Sheet 1');
  xlsx.writeFile(workBook, 'itemSheet.xlsx')



}
header: any = [{
  itemNumber: 'Item Number',
  itemDescription: 'Item Description',
  manufacturer: 'Manufacturer',
  manufacturerPartNumber: 'Manufacturer Part Number'

}];
item: any = [{
  itemNumber: 1,
  itemDescription: 'An Item',
  manufacturer: 'Manufacturer A',
  manufacturerPartNumber: 123
},{
  itemNumber: 2,
  itemDescription: 'Another Item',
  manufacturer: 'Manufacturer B',
  manufacturerPartNumber: 124
},{
  itemNumber: 3,
  itemDescription: 'Yet Another Item',
  manufacturer: 'Manufacturer C',
  manufacturerPartNumber: 125
}]


}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div #TABLE #table>
  <div class="row">  
      <div class="col-sm-12">
<table style="width: 100%" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class = 'thead-dark' *ngFor="let h of header">
    <th> {{ h.itemNumber }} </th>
    <th> {{ h.manufacturer }} </th>
    <th>{{ h.manufacturerPartNumber }}</th>
    <th>{{ h.itemDescription }}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let i of item">
      <td> {{ i.itemNumber }}</td>
      <td> {{ i.manufacturer }}</td>
      <td> {{ i.manufacturerPartNumber }}</td>
      <td> {{ i.itemDescription }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="xport()">Export to Excel</button>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide online stackblitz?

Comment: @SelakaN https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-write-excel

Comment: It doesnt get exported to excel

Comment: I currently have file type set to CSV but when I do .xlsx and I try to open file it says the extension is invalid

Comment: @SelakaN I have updated the question with an image of the error I am encountering hopefully this helps

Comment: Would you mind if I share some example which worked for me?

Comment: go for it do you want to move this to chat or did you want to submit as an answer

Comment: Will share a stackblitz example. You might have to change your logic according to that. Please marked it as correct and give it an upvote. Highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: There seems to be a bug in `npm` `xlsx` version `0.15`. I have forked your stackblitz and downgraded depencency to `xlsx` version `0.14`. Then it works. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-write-excel-fzl91x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html.